# How to retrieve daily punch time for user?

Tags: mysql

There I have a Punchtime table which contains the User Punchdata.

```
User    |   Punchtime   |   DatePunch   |   createdon
user1   |   08:57:26    |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02 15:09:46
user1   |   08:57:27    |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02 15:09:46
user2   |   14:11:29    |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02 15:09:46
user2   |   19:26:58    |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02 15:09:46
user1   |   18:27:00    |   2017-06-01  |   2017-06-02 15:09:47
```

I want to fetch minimum and maximum user punch time gourp by `DatePunch` with a diffrence of **three hour**.
If the diffrence is less then three hour found then `Outtime` will return as `null`

Desired Output will be like.

```
User    |   InTime      |   Outime      |   Date
user1   |   08:57:26    |   18:27:00    |   2017-06-01
user2   |   14:11:29    |   19:26:58    |   2017-06-01
```

Comment: Can you provide a more properly representative data set, and desired result. And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There I have a solution to my query but it seems it's too slow.Please provide some more suggestion if anyone has.

```
 SELECT User,CAST(MIN(Punchtime) AS TIME) AS InTime,
            (CASE
                WHEN
                    ((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(Punchtime),
                                    MIN(Punchtime))) / 3600) > 3)
                THEN
                    CAST(MAX(Punchtime) AS TIME)
                ELSE NULL
            END) AS OutTime
    FROM DailyPunchInOut GROUP BY Date,User
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT User, MIN(Punchtime) as InTime, IF((MAX(Punchtime) - MIN(Punchtime)) >= 3, MAX(Punchtime), NULL) as OutTime, DatePunch
FROM Punchtime
GROUP BY DatePunch
```

Comment: I guess it's lucky that there's only user.